# project_create.sh: line 4: android: command not found (cygwin&android&jni)

Tags: android, opencv, batch-file, java-native-interface, cygwin

http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Windows.pdf

This is the tutorial I am following and I stucked in the `JNI to opencv library`
according to the steps I had run `project_create.sh` in `cugwin` and come up with the result `project_create.sh: line 4: android: command not found`

Then I created a `project_create.bat` file with line `android update project --name android-opencv --path .\ copy project.properties  default.properties`

BUT it also come up with `android` is not recognized as an internal or external command/ operable program or batch file.

Both `.sh` and `.bat` didn't work and I couldn't move on. Because `ant` step depend on it
Could someone give me any idea how to fix it??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally I made it!

First of all, modified project_create.sh put the path to android like `C:/cygwin/home/Joyce/SDK/tools/android update project --name android-opencv --target 2 \ --path`

And better add up the target too because you don't have to deal with the "target not found" problem.

Second of all, don't run it in cygwin terminal, run `"sh ./project_create.sh"` in windows terminal.

Thirdly, make sure ant\bin had been added up to PATH, then can run `"ant debug"` in windows terminal.

Finally, got "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"! JNI to opencv library done!

Answer (score 0):

Android is an executable located in `<path-to-your-SDK>/tools/`. Unless your working directory is tools, or you have added it to your `PATH`, you will get this error.

To fix it, either edit the script to use the full path, or copy paste the files into the tools directory and run them.

Comment: hi THX for the answer BUT i have added <path-to-my-SDK>/tools/ to the PATH and it didnt change the result! So i was wondering how to edit the script to use the full path? like add up a line "android = <path to my SDK>/tools/"?  I cannot copy and paste the files into the tools directory because it is belong to an android-jni folder in opencv2.2.0.

Comment: Um, you're supposed to replace <path-to-your-SDK> with the actual path to your sdk.

Comment: i know:) i actually did change it as C:/cygwin/home/Username/SDK/tools

Comment: You can edit the script by just prefixing the path to the android command, so it'll become something like `<path>/tools/android`

Comment: okay  now the problem is "The system cannot find the path specified"        the lines in my project_create.bat are "android = C:/cygwin/home/Joyce/SDK/tools/android

android update project --name android-opencv --path .\ copy project.properties default.properties"

Comment: Try `C:/cygwin/home/Joyce/SDK/tools/android update project --name android-opencv --path .\ copy project.properties default.properties`

Comment: okay cool~ thank you so much it worked on android part! then "Argument 'default.properties' is not recognized"

Comment: oh actually i modified the project_create.sh in the same way and it worked! thank you so much about the full path idea! BUT now I had a problem about "'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command    operable program or bath file" and how should i do??? Thank you!!!